# EVERYTHING FINE BUT instead of show polyline getting error with invoked interface method Retrofit

Tags: android

[i think i do some mistake here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsPqz.png)

> Retrofit

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit =null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseURL){
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseURL).addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }return retrofit;
    }
}
```

> for Retrofit url calling

```
public class Common {
    public static final String baseUrl ="https://maps.googleapis.com";
    public static IGoogleApi getGoogleAPI(){
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(baseUrl).create(IGoogleApi.class);
    }
}
```

> for Retrofit call

```
package com.google.rishicab.Romote;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

public interface IGoogleApi {
    @GET
    Call<String> getPath(@Url String url);
}
```

I think some thing wrong I do with retrofit but cant find the mistake.

> logcat

```
createProgram 0x0000000800000000, binary 0x70f41ba6a3, length 10736, format 37168 within 518ns 
D/Gobinda: karnojora 
D/GOBINDA: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&transit_routing_preference=less_driving&origin=25.630044,88.1317314&destination=karnojora&key=AIzaSyDa-hkY6VKPVyhqpr********mw 
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call com.google.rishicab.Romote.IGoogleApi.getPath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference 
W/System.err:     at com.google.rishicab.MapsActivity.getDirection(MapsActivity.java:225)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just adding OkHttpClient for view Json file

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private  static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(){
        return  new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
               .build();
    }

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if(null == retrofit) {
            String baseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/";
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(getOkHttpClient())
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .build();
        }
        //return retrofit object
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case I'm run without Common class

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit =null;
public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if(null == retrofit) {
            String baseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/";
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(getOkHttpClient())
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .build();
        }
        //return retrofit object
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

init after onCreate

```
mServices= RetrofitClient.getClient().create(IGoogleApi.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

I also facing same problem solution use the lower version of retrofit

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0'
```